# Why is this program not exiting as expected. In Visual Studio a breakpoint is hit. Dynamic pointer is used in the program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers

I am learning dynamic memory allocation in CPP using pointers. The code is running as expected but not exiting as I want it to. The code runs into an error in Visual Studio. Here is a snapshot of the error.

Also, the destructor destroys the pointer but still no appropriate output.
I can't get the reason why the code crashes.

[image]

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
public:
    int* ptrDynamic = new int(5);
    void showAddress()
    {
        cout << "Address of the Pointer: " << &ptrDynamic << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            cout << "Address of " << i + 1 << "element:  " << &ptrDynamic[i] << endl;
            // Alternate method of showing address
            cout << "Address of " << i + 1 << "element:  " << ptrDynamic + i << endl;
            cout << endl << endl;
        }
    }

    void inputData()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            cout << "Enter Data at Index " << i + 1 << ":   ";
            //cin >> ptrDynamic[i]; Alternate method of accessing DMA index
            cin >> *(ptrDynamic + i);
        }
    }

    void showData()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            //cout << ptrDynamic[i] << endl;  Alternate method of accessing DMAint
            cout << *(ptrDynamic + i)<<endl;
        }
    }

    ~MyClass()
    {
        delete ptrDynamic;
    }
private:
};

int main()
{
    MyClass object{};
    object.showAddress();
    object.inputData();
    object.showData();

    getchar();  // Pausing the console to exit until an input is received.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've corrupted memory.  It looks like you intend to allocate an array of 5 `int`s, but you're actually allocating a single `int` with the value 5.  In principle, you've invoked undefined behavior.  In practice, the memory corruption (from `inputData`) likely causes `delete ptrDynamic` to crash when `MyClass` is destroyed.  You probably meant to use `new int[5];` (and `delete[]`), although you almost always should avoid using `new[]`/`delete[]` in real world C++ code.

Comment: Unrelated to the specific error, that `dynamicPtr` member should really be `private` not `public`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the very top of the class it should be

```
int* ptrDynamic = new int[5];
```

rather than

```
int* ptrDynamic = new int(5);
```

Square brackets means allocate an array of 5 elements. Round brackets means allocate a single int of value 5.

Also, the delete should be

```
delete [] ptrDynamic;
```

to deallocate the whole array, not just a single object.